# How to apply a long block of css to one whole div section (login form)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a login form section that I have enclosed inside a div. I want this section of the page *only* to be styled by the css shown below. However, when I add the css in the style, it isn't applied. I think it is down to syntax. I am trying to add styles within styles.

```
<div class="login-form">
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
```

The existing css is below (note there is bootstrap enabled and the bottom part of the css is relevant to another part of the site -the intro part and div)

It's in the first part

```
 .login-form {
    
    body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

that I've tried to refer to the div class for the form I want styled.

```
<style>


.login-form {

body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
form {border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

img.avatar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

}

    
.intro-text {
  
  width: 1000px;
  padding:15px;
  margin:40;
}
```

Can someone point out the error with some best practices on applying several styles to one div. I have already applied styles correctly, as can be seen with the

```
intro-text {
      
      width: 1000px;
      padding:15px;
      margin:40;
    }
```

which is correctly applied to:

```
<div class="intro-text">
<h1 class="display-5">Login</h1>
     <p>Welcome back</p>    
</div>
```

I cannot figure out how to apply the more complex styles to just the login-form div class and have tried several things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css you have is not valid. You cannot nest css blocks like that. I would recommend take a look at the [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Let's say you want to target a button inside the div with class `login-form`. Instead of doing this:

```
.login-form{
    button{
        //this doesn't work
    }
}
```

You should do this:

```
.login-form button{
    //css here
}
```

```css
.login-form {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.login-form form {border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;}
  
.login-form input[type=text], .login-form input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
.login-form button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
  
.login-form button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
  
.login-form .cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}
  
.login-form .imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}
  
.login-form img.avatar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
  
.login-form .container {
  padding: 16px;
}
  
.login-form span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}
    
.intro-text {
  
  width: 1000px;
  padding:15px;
  margin:40;
}

Here is a snippet with the proper css:
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div class="login-form">
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: just trying our your suggestion. For the first bit, don't I need to specify body: .login-form {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}  very helpful so far thanks.

Comment: Also - there must be an easier way - this seems to defeat the purpose of having a div or class

Comment: depends what you want to do. If the font is for the entire page, you should do: `body{ font-family...}`. If you want to apply it only on the div, you can just do `.login-form{font-family...}`. Doing `body .login-form{...}` will target the same div, so it's not necessary

Comment: you can say just `button{...}`, but that will target all of your buttons, not just the ones inside that div. It depends what you want to achieve.
If you really want to use nested blocks, you should take a look at scss instead of css.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax use is not correct , nesting in css shoud be in you case like

```
.login-form form {
   // css code here 
}
```

so apply selector and space and other selector for nesting properties
so every css rules in your code to be applyed only to this page , should be preceded with parent selector (.login-form) in your case .

but for the body , it cant be applied by this way ,

to apply some font for only this page , you could use by example :

adding class to body in this page then apply css as :

```
<body class="login-page">

   // rest of html

</body>
```

and css should be :

```
body.login-page {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

Also I forget to mention that the syntax you used before, is like the [scss](https://sass-lang.com/guide) syntax, but it should be precompiled to browser understandable css formt , thus you project should as modern web project to precompile scss to css .